# Build a ranking list with difference from previous postion, like ranking 2 (+6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm trying to build a ranking list based on votes (on Ruby on Rails)

I do not have ranking and increment values.
My table has ~300 records

```
post id,  votes,  ranking,  increment 
1,        22,     1,        +3
2,        16,     2,        -1
3,        13,     3,        +6
4,        7,      4,        -2
```

I'm confused about how to build the increment part, like, how many positions went up or down based on the previous postion.

I'm wondering how can I build this
Should I use a `cron` job that run daily/hourly that updates ranking an increment based on votes ?

How can I calculate ranking and increment? Should I have a prev_ranking column instead of increment ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it too large of a sample to user `.sort`? After a new ranking, sort by avg ranking.

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm actually trying to calculate the ranking and prev ranking.. any idea how to write a sql to calculate that based on the votes column?

Comment: In that case, I think previous ranking works well. Then just compare the two columns. The logic would be simpler. In your controller, when a vote is triggered. Update the previous ranking column with the current index. Then, add the new vote. Then sort. Then add update the current ranking column based on the new index. Compare.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion you can do is use background task libraries like Resque to queue jobs and Resque scheduler to run in background

With that you can do a daily/hourly task to look at current ranking, calculate new ranking based on new votes, then find differences between new ranking vs current ranking to get the change in rankings

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually confused about how the actual SQL should look like to update the ranking and calculate the prev ranking .. any help on that?